# Match a pattern between the www. and .com parts of a web address

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am writing a program which gives me the letters containing only the consonants in a webpage address between www. and .com.
For example if I input www.google.com it should return me 'ggl' but that doesnt happen.

```
import re

x=int(raw_input())

for i in range(x):
    inp1=raw_input()
    y=re.findall('^www\.[^(aeiou)]+\.com',inp1)
    print y
    inp2=y[0]
    print inp2
```

So what's the mistake in the line `y=re.findall('^www\.[^aeiou]+\.com',inp1)`?

Comment: Did you [tested](https://regex101.com/r/dV9mX6/1) it?

Comment: You have several mistakes but the main one is you think regex is smart enough to understand human logic. You should remove `www.` and `.com` from the input and use `[^aeiou]` regex in the `re.finall` call. Or a `[aeiou]` regex with `re.sub`.

Comment: won't need a regex `''.join([i for i in s.split('.')[1] if s.split('.')[1].isalpha() and i not in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')])`

Comment: Regex is legitimate enough to understand what we want , given that the syntax is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a regex and you don't need a variable-width lookbehind to achieve it. You can use a negative lookahead:

```
>>> s = 'www.google.com'
>>> re.findall('(?!w{1,3}\.)([^aeiou\W])(?=.*\.com)', s)
['g', 'g', 'l']
```

[Click here](https://regex101.com/r/tQ6bP2/1) for a step-by-step explanation of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with a regex. To find all matches while always checking for the preceding `www.`, you'd need variable-width lookbehinds, which are illegal.

If they worked though, which, again, they do not, the following regex would have been what you were looking for:

```
y=re.findall('(?<=^www\..*)[^aeiou]+(?=.*?\.com)',inp1)
```

The answer however is simply that you cannot do what you're looking to do, with a regex.